# Update contents of Android App on update of WordPress website

Tags: android, wordpress

I am quite new to Android App Development. This could be a very basic question for gurus...
Here is my scenario!

I've a website developed in wordpress. Users generally post stories / articles / news on this site. I want to develop an Android app for this site. Whenever a new story is posted, I want the android app to know about it and update the contents to display the latest post. This should be done silently meaning no action shall be needed from user.

Thanks in advance

Vaibhav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the simpliest way to achieve this would be use an RSS feed and an Android application generator. The idea is that the application watches the RSS feed and shows the latest content from there. I'm not familiar with Wordpress but I'm sure it's possible to get RSS working there.

Google around for something like `android app generator RSS`. For example, [TheAppBuilder](http://www.theappbuilder.com/) mentions [support for wordpress](http://www.theappbuilder.com/howto.html). Another generator is [AppYet](http://www.appyet.com/) and there are many more.

Comment: +1 to AppYet. It's quite limited, but it's completely free for free apps. In fact, you can make some money with it if you link your AdMob account.